# button click event in jquery is not triggered for asp button

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-group-lg" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Sign in" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

This is my button. I have a javascript file `<script src="Scripts/jsFile.js"></script>` Where i have written below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divMain').hide().fadeIn(2000)

    $(document).on("click", "#btnSubmit", function (e) {
        alert('The element myID is clicked');
    });
});
```

fadeIn functionality works however click is not triggered. I need to do something else??

Comment: set `ClientIDMode = Static` of `#btnSubmit` button.

Comment: Put e.preventDefault (); just before the alert statement. Also you don't need OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"

Answer (score 1):

Possible issue is your jquery script is unable to find the id thats why event is not firing.

Try using the

```
 '<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>'
```

This will work very fast as it will use native `document.getElementById`.
in your selector.
As server control id generation pattern is something you dont want to dependent on.

**OR**

As mentioned by @Kartikey
You can set the `ClientIDMode = Static` of `#btnSubmit` button